# Positional argument for subparser raises the error: invalid choice

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am new to `argsparse` thus this might pretty sure be a newbie mistake so please bare with me. My code:

```
import argsparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Argument Parser')
subparsers = parent_parser.add_subparsers(title="Sub-commands", description='Sub-commands Parser')
parser_create = subparsers.add_parser('run', parents=[parent_parser], add_help=False, help="run the program")
parser_create.add_argument('--program', metavar=('NAME'), required=True, type=str, help='name of the program')
```

This works perfectly fine when running `parser.py run --program 'test'` in the console:

`args = parent_parser.parse_args(); print(args)` outputs `Namespace(program='test')`

However, when I try to replace the optional argument with a positional one like:

```
parser_create.add_argument('program', metavar=('NAME'), type=str, help='name of the program')
```

And then run `parser.py run 'test'` in the console the following error is raised:

```
usage: parser.py run [-h] {run} ... NAME
parser.py run: error: invalid choice: 'test' (choose from 'run')
```

Adding the positional argument to a group results in the same error as above:

```
required = parser_create.add_argument_group('required positional argument')
required.add_argument('program', metavar=('NAME'), type=str, help='name of the program')
```

How can I pass positional arguments to the subparser formatted as `run <program>`?

I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @PhilippSelenium for pointing out the link to the docs.

I solved this by removing `parents=[parent_parser]` from `subparsers.add_parser()`

Comment: using the parents created a kind of recursive subparser mechanism expecting `prog.py run run run ...`